# Error when trying to write script results into table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a script that runs correctly pasted below:

```
SELECT s2.*, 
       c.customerid 
      ,c.[CustomerGender]
      ,c.[CustomerIsRegistered]
      ,c.[CustomerCreatedDate]
      ,c.[UpdatedDate]
      ,c.[CustomerAcquiredDate]
      ,c.[CustomerSource]
      ,c.[NumberOfChildren]
      ,c.[campaign]
      ,c.[EmailOptIn]
      ,c.[CommunicationGroup]
      ,c.[event_type],
       r.voucherstartdate, 
       r.voucherenddate, 
       r.createddate, 
       r.createdtime, 
       r.vouchercode 

FROM   pebi_warehouse.olap.dimcustomer_eventstream c 
       JOIN pebi_warehouse.[warehouse].[factvoucherissued_eventstream] r 
         ON c.customerid = r.eventhubkey 
       JOIN (SELECT transactionnumber, 
                    calendarsalesbusinessdateid, 
                    locationkey, 
                    retailid, 
                    vouchercode 
             FROM   [db_owner].[sk_sales_2019_2]) s 
         ON s.calendarsalesbusinessdateid BETWEEN 
            r.voucherstartdate AND r.voucherenddate 
            AND s.locationkey = r.locationkey 
            AND r.vouchercode = s.vouchercode 
       JOIN (SELECT transactionnumber, 
                    calendarsalesbusinessdateid, 
                    locationkey, 
                    retailid, 
                    vouchercode, 
                   sum([SalesQuantity]) as SalesQuantity
                  ,sum([SalesCover]) as SalesCover
                  ,sum([SalesGrossAmountCCY]) as SalesGrossAmountCCY
                  ,sum([SalesAmountCCY]) as SalesAmountCCY
                  ,sum([SalesTaxAmountCCY]) as SalesTaxAmountCCY
                  ,sum([SalesDonationAmountCCY]) as SalesDonationAmountCCY
                  ,sum([SalesNetAmount]) as SalesNetAmount
                  ,sum([SalesPromotionAmountCCY]) as SalesPromotionAmountCCY
                  ,sum([SalesEVoucher1Amount]) as SalesEVoucher1Amount
                  ,sum([SalesEVoucher2Amount]) as SalesEVoucher2Amount
                  ,sum([SalesEVoucher3Amount]) as SalesEVoucher3Amount
                  ,sum([SalesAdjustmentAmount]) as SalesAdjustmentAmount
                  ,sum([SalesAdjustmentAmountExcludingVAT]) as SalesAdjustmentAmountExcludingVAT
                  ,sum([SalesNetAdjustedAmount]) as SalesNetAdjustedAmount
                  ,sum([CostPrice]) as CostPrice
                  ,sum([SalesPromotionAmountExcludingVAT]) as SalesPromotionAmountExcludingVAT
                  ,sum([GrossSalesCF]) as GrossSalesCF
             FROM   [db_owner].[sk_sales_2019_2] 
             GROUP  BY transactionnumber, 
                       calendarsalesbusinessdateid, 
                       locationkey, 
                       retailid, 
                       vouchercode) s2 
         ON s2.transactionnumber = s.transactionnumber 
            AND s2.calendarsalesbusinessdateid = s.calendarsalesbusinessdateid 
            AND s2.locationkey = s.locationkey 
            AND s2.retailid = s.retailid
```

However, I want to write the results of this into a SQL table so have updated the query to:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.sk_cust_2019_helper 
AS
    (SELECT 
         s2.*, 
         c.customerid,
         c.[CustomerGender],
         c.[CustomerIsRegistered],
         c.[CustomerCreatedDate],
         c.[UpdatedDate],
         c.[CustomerAcquiredDate],
         c.[CustomerSource],
         c.[NumberOfChildren],
         c.[campaign],
         c.[EmailOptIn],
         c.[CommunicationGroup],
         c.[event_type],
         r.voucherstartdate, 
         r.voucherenddate, 
         r.createddate, 
         r.createdtime, 
         r.vouchercode 
     FROM   
         pebi_warehouse.olap.dimcustomer_eventstream c 
     JOIN 
         pebi_warehouse.[warehouse].[factvoucherissued_eventstream] r 
             ON c.customerid = r.eventhubkey 
     JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              transactionnumber, 
              calendarsalesbusinessdateid, 
              locationkey, 
              retailid, 
              vouchercode 
          FROM   
              [db_owner].[sk_sales_2019_2]) s  ON s.calendarsalesbusinessdateid BETWEEN r.voucherstartdate AND r.voucherenddate 
                                               AND s.locationkey = r.locationkey 
                                               AND r.vouchercode = s.vouchercode 
     JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              transactionnumber, 
              calendarsalesbusinessdateid, 
              locationkey, 
              retailid, 
              vouchercode, 
              SUM([SalesQuantity]) AS SalesQuantity,
              SUM([SalesCover]) AS SalesCover,
              SUM([SalesGrossAmountCCY]) AS SalesGrossAmountCCY, 
              SUM([SalesAmountCCY]) AS SalesAmountCCY,
              SUM([SalesTaxAmountCCY]) AS SalesTaxAmountCCY,
              SUM([SalesDonationAmountCCY]) AS SalesDonationAmountCCY,
              SUM([SalesNetAmount]) AS SalesNetAmount,
              SUM([SalesPromotionAmountCCY]) AS SalesPromotionAmountCCY,
              SUM([SalesEVoucher1Amount]) AS SalesEVoucher1Amount,
              SUM([SalesEVoucher2Amount]) AS SalesEVoucher2Amount,
              SUM([SalesEVoucher3Amount]) AS SalesEVoucher3Amount,
              SUM([SalesAdjustmentAmount]) AS SalesAdjustmentAmount,
              SUM([SalesAdjustmentAmountExcludingVAT]) AS SalesAdjustmentAmountExcludingVAT,
              SUM([SalesNetAdjustedAmount]) AS SalesNetAdjustedAmount,
              SUM([CostPrice]) AS CostPrice,
              SUM([SalesPromotionAmountExcludingVAT]) AS SalesPromotionAmountExcludingVAT,
              SUM([GrossSalesCF]) AS GrossSalesCF,
          FROM   
              [db_owner].[sk_sales_2019_2] 
          GROUP BY 
              transactionnumber, 
              calendarsalesbusinessdateid, 
              locationkey, 
              retailid, 
              vouchercode) s2 ON s2.transactionnumber = s.transactionnumber 
                              AND s2.calendarsalesbusinessdateid = s.calendarsalesbusinessdateid 
                              AND s2.locationkey = s.locationkey 
                              AND s2.retailid = s.retailid);
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Can someone help me understand how to update my script so I can write the results into a new SQL table?

Comment: SQL Server does not support the standard CREATE TABLE AS. You need to use `select .. into new_table from ...`

Comment: To supplement horse's comment, [SELECT - INTO Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql).

Comment: Where do I put the INTO? I get the error in comment below when i try the below ```SELECT s2.*, 
       c.customerid 
      ,c.[CustomerGender]
      ,c.[CustomerIsRegistered]
      ,c.[CustomerCreatedDate]
      ,c.[UpdatedDate]
      ,c.[CustomerAcquiredDate]
      ,c.[CustomerSource]
      ,c.[NumberOfChildren]
      ,c.[campaign]
      ,c.[EmailOptIn]
      ,c.[CommunicationGroup]
      ,c.[event_type],
       r.voucherstartdate, 
       r.voucherenddate, 
       r.createddate, 
       r.createdtime, 
       r.vouchercode 
INTO dbo.sk_cust_2019_helper
FROM  ....

Comment: Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'vouchercode' in table 'sk_cust_2019_helper' is specified more than once.

Comment: I think I have worked it out. Thank you for the help. Good to know SQL server doesn't support CREATE TABLE AS

Answer (score 0):

Use "select * into" to create new table